# auto redirect from "/" path to "/login" or "/admin"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I need to make an automatic redirection when the app starts at "localhost:3000/". that means to make a redirect from "/" to "/login" or "/admin" automatically.

i tried to make this:

```js
imports ...... 

class App extends react component {

state = {isAuth:false}


func = () => {
//axios function that goes to node.js to pass json-web-token and receive payload.
if success: this setState({isAuth:true})

}

render () {

if (!isAuth) return <Redirect to="/login">

if (isAuth) return <Redirect to="/admin">


return (
      <Router>
       {this.func()}
        <div className="App">
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/addNewVacation" component= 
              {VacationAdder} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calls to axios are asynchronous, so you need to do an await when calling axios, and declare